# Callback in JQuery Animate

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jquery-animate, jquery-callback

I am using the following JQuery code to open a pair of doors that start off closed. Different menu items cause the doors to close and then reopen with corresponding pictures underneath. Everything works smoothly except the first time the doors are opened, the right door div snaps back to its initial spot and animates again. What am I doing wrong here? Please look at the #leftdoor and #rightdoor these are the divs I'm having an issue with.

```
    var doorOpen = false;

        $("a[href=#bugz]").click(function() {

            // If door is open then close doors
            if (doorOpen) { 
                var duration = 1000;
            } else {
                var duration = 0;
            }

            $('.title1,.title2,.title3,.title4,.title5,.fade1,.fade2,.fade3,.fade4,.fade5,').animate({
            opacity: 0,
            }, 1000);
            $('.fade5,.fade2,.fade3,.fade4').css('zIndex', 1);
            $('.fade1').css('zIndex', 20);

            $("#rightdoor,#leftdoor").animate(
                {"marginLeft":"0px"},
                {duration:duration,
                    complete:function() {
                        $('.pic2,.pic3,.pic4,.pic5').css('zIndex', 1);  //puts wrong pics in back
                        $('.pic1').css('zIndex', 2);  //brings right pic into view
                        $('#rightdoor').animate({  //opens doors again
                         marginLeft: "150px",
                        }, 1000);
                        $('#leftdoor').animate({
                         marginLeft: "-150px",
                        }, 1000);
                        $('.title1').animate({
                        "opacity": "0.75",
                        }, 1000);
                        $('.fade1').animate({
                        "opacity": "1",
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            );

            doorOpen = true;


        });
```

Every time this is run again, it works fine. It's just the first time when the doors start out closed that the problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

try

```
doorOpen = true;
return false;

//instead of 
doorOpen = true;
```

if that doesn't work

try

```
$("a[href=#bugz]").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
```

Comment: No luck. If it helps any - the doors open and <i>then</i> right door resets and opens again at the same time as the .fade1 and .title1 classes. After the first time, the .fade1, .title1, and the opening of the doors animate in synchrony

Comment: Try $("#leftdoor,#rightdoor").animate instead.  I am curious to see what happens.  I don't have time to load this up and try to test it right now so this is all shots-in-the-dark.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that earlier.It didn't change anything though. thanks anyway

Comment: What is the margin of the right door before the animation script is called?